# Is there a way to point many domain names to the same IP without repeating the IP

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I own about 100 domain names. Most of them are unused, but I have them all set up to point to the same server so that I can serve a redirect to my main domain name.

Right now, I'm using A records for each domain to point to my server. I'm about to change servers, which means I'll need to change IPs. Using Google Cloud DNS (or any DNS provider), is there a way to use some sort of root CNAME or variable so that I don't have to change the IP 100 times?

I'd love to be able to update a single domain's A record, and then see the rest update automatically, but I don't see a way to make a CNAME record on a non-subdomain, only an A record.

Comment: You can try '*.domain.name' to CNAME or to A